# Alterar div PAI dentro de um frame Filho

Tags: javascript, jquery

Vou tentar melhorar a dúvida.

Tenho uma pagina principal.html que está assim:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id='divPai'>Sou a div PAI!</div>
    <frame id='framePai' src='filho.html'></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Na pagina filho.html gostaria algo assim:

```
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick='alteraPai()'>Alterar DIV Pai</button>

    <script>
        function alteraPai() {
            deAlgumaFormaPaginaPai.divPai.innerHTML = "Mudei!";
            // ou
            $("#deAlgumaFormaTambem").html("Mudei!");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que tenha ficado mais claro.
Obrigado galera!!

Comment: Oi Wesley! Podes dar um exemplo de HTML e JavaScript que não funcione? Assim podemos ver e ajudar no que falta.

Comment: Oi Sérgio!
Rapaz já tentei de tudo mas não consigo alterar um elemento da pagina principal de dentro do iFrame.

Comment: O que eu quero é que coloques o HTML que não consegues por a funcionar

Comment: Veja se ajuda Sergio.
Obrigado maninhooo!!

Answer (score 1):

Podes aceder ao pai da página dentro da iframe com `window.parent.document`.
Repara também que tens `frame` em vez de `iframe`.

Podes fazer isso assim: 
(repara nos exemplos no jsFiddle)

Na página Pai:

```
<div id='divPai'>Sou a div PAI!</div>
<iframe id='framePai' src='/5kfvndmz/show'></iframe>
```

([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30jtgs8n/))

Na pagina filho.html

```
<button onclick='alteraPai()'>Alterar DIV Pai</button>

<script>
function alteraPai() {
    const parentDocument =  window.parent.document;
        const divPai = parentDocument.getElementById('divPai');
        divPai.innerHTML = "Mudei!";
}
</script>
```

[(jsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/5kfvndmz/show)